# Как в Java удалить все "небуквенные" символы в строке используя regex?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно удалить все небуквенные символы - то есть все, кроме [a-zA-z].
Есть строка `string`, и её нужно обработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
string = string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+","");
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116264/discussion-on-answer-by-----java----).

Comment: `A-z` - это неверно всегда.

Answer (score 0):

- `[^\p{L}]+` - найдет вхождения, которые не буквы
- `^[^\p{L}]+$` - чекнет, что весть текст состоит не из букв

Плюс, работает с любым языком

Comment: Мне нужно не просто регулярное выражение, а конкретно как будет выглядеть функция

Comment: @МаксимФалеев тогда советую начать с основных основ, а не регулярных выражений